# mounting network drive in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

The following command correctly mounts a network drive for me:

```
sudo mount   192.168.0.15:/drive /media/data
```

Yet the following entry in **/etc/fstab** does not work. Why?

```
 //192.168.0.15/drive  /media/data/ cifs    uid=1000    0   0
```

Error:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
FAIL: 32
```

Comment: Is the trailing slash in `/media/data/` tripping it up?

Comment: dynamic syntax look nfs mount to me not cifs. if you issue `mount` or `mount -p` which protocol is used ?

Comment: you were correct archemar I did not realise the drive was nfs.
This works:
192.168.0.15:/drive  /media/data nfs defaults 0   0

Answer (score 1):

Usually a network drive is not written in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
//192.168.0.15/drive  /media/data/ cifs    uid=1000    0   0
```

I would use

```
192.168.0.15:/drive  /media/data cifs    uid=1000    0   0
```

i.e., the same form as used on the command-line.  Presumably the network *is* `cifs`, and there's no problem with the `uid` clause (because we cannot determine that without checking the output of your successful `mount` command).